# Php: Reliable way to check if there is a query AND whether the GET argument is passed

Tags: php

Really new to PHP...

I would like to have a PHP interface which takes day, month, and year arguments as 'd', 'm', 'y', where the default values are simply pulled from the current date.

My thinking is that that should look something like this:

```
$day = isset($_GET) && isset($_GET['d']) ? $_GET['d'] : date('d');
```

But I seem to be missing something. Do I need the first `isset($_GET)` or is that redundant?

Comment: So, you just want to get the current day, year and month?

Comment: If they are not passed as part of the query

Comment: Then @RobbieAverill answer will most likely help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$_GET` is always going to be set, so yes - that part is redundant.

```
$day = isset($_GET['d']) ? $_GET['d'] : date('d');
```

This would be fine for any PHP version, including PHP 5.x.

In PHP 7 you can shorten this by using [the null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op):

```
$day = $_GET['d'] ?? date('d');
```